# VS Project configuration - should I split web app and API interface into two separate projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I've got a pretty simple question: I have a VS solution composed of two ASP.NET/C# projects right now. One is a service that listens over a url to send and receive messages to an API.  It takes the messages and puts them in a database, etc.  The other project contains all the website code for users to access the API info.  It also allows users to send messages via the a class in the first project.  The two projects listen on different ports.

My basic question is this: is it a good idea to keep them separate so that they are listening on different ports, or should I combine them into one project.  And if I do combine them, is there a way to have them listen on different ports if that is a good idea?  Combining them seems like it would be best for simplicity, so is there really much reason not to?

Thank you.  I'm still new to C#/ASP.NET, so please bear that in mind if the answer is obvious.

Comment: I don't really get it. It sounds like you have 2 Web APIs, but at the same time... no? When you say API do you mean Web API or do you mean Class Library? Also, the port configuration would be done at the IIS level.

Comment: your question seems off topic on SO try instead http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have one API, and another site for users to login and access their accounts